# Hyperlink to "head" revision in JS Bin

Tags: links, js-bin

JS Bin is a great tool for quickly throwing together examples and sharing them with others.  However, as I modify the code, it would be ideal to be able to send others a permanent link to the "head" revision rather than having to continuously update them (or my notes).

How?

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure about JS Bin been able to do so however I can offer you an alternative

jsfiddle.net

Example
http://jsfiddle.net/ZRvJG/

Edits:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZRvJG/1/

Hope this helps

EDIT:

If you sign up to js fiddle you can set the "base revision"

http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html?highlight=head#setting-base-version

Meaning if you dont have the /1/ on the end or what ever number it will show the base version - which you could set to the head

Comment: Very very cool... although it's still not doing what I wanted.  If I go to http://jsfiddle.net/ZRvJG/ I see your first edit.  The head currently has an altogether uninteresting message to you.

Comment: @John sorry clearly miss read that question, see edit